# Showing that $V_k/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite extension for $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

If we define each $V_k$ recursively by $V_k=V_{k-1}(2^{\frac{1}{k}})$, then how would one show that $V_k/\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite extension for each index $k\in \mathbb{N}$?

Here is my approach: each $V_k/\mathbb{Q}$ would have to be finite for each $k$ since the element $2^{\frac{1}{k}} \in V_k$ would have to be algebraic over the field $\mathbb{Q}$. It is the root of the polynomial $x^{k}-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, which implies that the algebraic degree of $2^{\frac{1}{k}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ would be at most $k$, therefore making $V_k/\mathbb{Q}$ finite. Am I missing something here / misunderstanding something crucial?

Comment: You forgot to define $V_1=\mathbb{Q}$ (or some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$).  Then you will need to use tower law inductively, because $V_k$ is not $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/k})$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following:

1. If $L/K$ and $K/F$ are finite extensions of fields, then $L/F$ is also a finite extension, i.e., $\dim_F(L) < \infty$.
2. If $K \subset L$ is an extension such that $L = K(a)$ for some *algebraic* $a \in L$, then $L/K$ is finite.

By 2., it follows that $V_k/V_{k-1}$ is finite since $2^{1/k}$ satisfies $$x^k - 2 \in V_{k - 1}[x]\setminus\{0\}.$$ By induction and 1., it follows that $V_k/V_1$ is finite for all $k$. I'm guessing that $V_1 = \Bbb Q$, so then you are done.

(All you need is that $V_1/\Bbb Q$ is a finite extension.)